# LINQ statement to get every recipe with list of ingridients

Tags: c#, .net, linq, unit-of-work

I have a question regarding the LINQ and foreach.

Lets say I have a simple DB with three tables (`ingredient`, `recipe` and many-to many relation `ingredientinrecipe`). They all have the simple structure of id and name.

I am running a console application where user could enter two `ingredients` for example

```
egg, flour
```

How would I structure the LINQ clause to go through all recipes where these both would be inside.

I am using UOW to structure everything together, so I could do `uow.Ingridients.All` ... etc etc

I figured I need to approach it from `ingridientinrecipe` table.

It would be something following:

```
var recipes = uow.ingridientinrecipe.All.Where(a => a.Ingridient.IngridientName.Contains( ...
```

But this works if and only if user enters one ingridient. How would I expand it to use two to infinite inputs.

I add what I have done so far.

```
var line = Console.ReadLine();
while (line.ToLower().Trim() != "exit")
{
    var ingridients= line.Split(',');
    Console.WriteLine("\nAre you looking for following receipes:");
    foreach (var ingridient in ingridients)
    {
        var recipes= _uow.IngridientInRecipe.All.Where(a => a.Ingridient.IngridientName.Contains(ingridient)).ToList();
        foreach (var recipe in recipes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(recipe.Recipes.RecipeName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        line = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

TABLE STRUCTURE AS ASKED

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int RecipeId{ get; set; }

    public string RecipeName{ get; set; }

    public virtual List<IngridientInRecipe> IngridientInRecipe{ get; set; }
}


public class Symptom
{
    public int IngridientId{ get; set; }
    public string IngridientName{ get; set; }

    public virtual List<IngridientInRecipe> IngridientInRecipe{ get; set; }

}

public class IngridientInRecipe
{

    public int IngridientInRecipeId{ get; set; }

    public int RecipeId{ get; set; }
    public virtual Recipe Recipe{ get; set; }

    public int IngridientId{ get; set; }
    public virtual Ingridient Ingridient{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's spelled "ingredient"

Comment: I have been trying to write the solution but I need you to share the tables structure, please.

Comment: @Veverke Added it !

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345609(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var line = Console.ReadLine();
while (line.ToLower().Trim() != "exit")
{
    var ingridients = line.Split(',');
    Console.WriteLine("\nAre you looking for following receipes:");
    var recipes = _uow.IngridientInRecipe.All;
    foreach (var ingridient in ingridients)
    {
        recipes = recipes.Intersect(_uow.IngridientInRecipe.All.Where(a => a.Ingridient.IngridientName.Contains(ingridient)));
    }
    foreach (var recipe in recipes.ToList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(recipe.Recipes.RecipeName);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    line = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. It goes through first time, but the second time it runs through ingridients foreach it does not find anything.
Even though recipe clearly has that ingridient!

Comment: problem seems to be that second time it goes through that list, the recipe ingredients only have the ingridients that got into list the first time it went through.  I assume somehow i would need to include every ingredient in that specific recipe.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `PredicateBuilder` from [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) (I have no affiliation with this):

```
var ingredients = ingredientList.ToLower().Split(new [] { ';', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Recipe>();

foreach (var ingredient in ingredients)
{
    string temp = ingredient;  // To avoid passing the loop variable into a closure
    predicate = predicate.Or(r => r.Ingredients.Contains(temp);
}

reportQuery = reportQuery.Where(predicate);
```